# How to save output of my loop in a dataframe R studio

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

[image]

I have a dataframe (check the picture). I am creating periods of 30 values and I am calculating how many of this values are over 0.1. At the end, I want  to save all the 336 outputs in a dataframe (as a row). How could I do that? My code is failing!

```
i <- 0
secos=as.data.frame(NULL)
for (i in c(0:336)){
hola=as.data.frame(pp[c(1+i:29 + i)])
secos[[i]]=sum(hola > 0.1)
secos=rbind(secos[[i]])}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iteratively building (growing) `data.frame`s in R is a bad thing. For good reading, see the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), chapter 2 on *Growing Objects*. Bottom line, though: it works, but as you add more rows, it will get progressively slower and use (at least) twice as much memory as you intend.
2. You explicitly overwrite `secos` with `rbind(secos[[i]])`, where the rbind call is a complete no-op doing nothing. (e.g., see `identical(rbind(mtcars), mtcars)`). Back to (1), best to `L <- lapply(0:336, function(i) ...)` then `secos <- do.call(rbind, L)`.
3. R indexes are 1-based, but your first call assigns to `secos[[0]]` which fails.

A literal translation of this into a better start is something like the following. (Up front, your reference to `pp` only makes sense if you have an object `pp` that you used to create your `data.frame` above ... since `pp[.]` by itself will not reference the frame. If you're using `attach(.)` to be able to do that, then ... don't. Too many risks and things that can go wrong with it, it is one of the base functions I'd vote to remove.)

```r
invec <- 0:336
L <- sapply(invec, function(i) {
  hola=as.data.frame(pp[c(1+i:29 + i)])
  sum(hola > 0.1)
})
secos <- data.frame(i = invec, secos = L)
```

An alternative:

```r
L <- lapply(invec, function(i) {
  hola=as.data.frame(pp[c(1+i:29 + i)])
  data.frame(secos = sum(hola > 0.1))
})
out <- do.call(rbind, L)
```

I can't help but think there is a more efficient, R-*idiomatic* way to aggregate this data. My guess is that it's a moving window of sorts, perhaps a month wide (or similar). If that's the case, I recommend looking into `zoo::rollapply(pp, 30, function(z) sum(z > 0.1))`, perhaps with meaningful application of `align=`, `partial=`, and/or `fill=`.